# pass dynamic values as a variable on to xslt 1.0 with java

Tags: java, transform, xslt-1.0

I need to pass a variable from java code to xslt.
1) this is my xslt

```
<xsl:output method="xml" encoding="utf-8" indent="yes" />
<xsl:param name="rendered_id"></xsl:param>
<xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:apply-templates />
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="node()" />
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="status">
    <xsl:if test="name = '$rendered_id'">
        <status>
            <xsl:apply-templates />
        </status>
    </xsl:if>
</xsl:template>
```

2) i need to get the dynamic value to $rendered_id. But it does not work
3) my java code

```
    TransformerFactory transformerFactory = TransformerFactory.newInstance();
            StreamSource streamSource = new StreamSource(
                    new File("conv.xsl"));
            Transformer transformer = transformerFactory.newTransformer(streamSource);
            JAXBContext jc =JAXBContext.newInstance(Statuses.class);
            JAXBSource jAXBSource = new JAXBSource(jc, status);
jAXBResult = new JAXBResult(JAXBContext.newInstance(Statuses.class));

            transformer.setParameter("rendered_id", "bag");
            transformer.transform(jAXBSource, jAXBResult);
```

Appreciate if you can help me on this.

Comment: At first glance everything looks correct. Can you show the source XML?

Comment: Source XML is <statuses>
    <result>name</result>
<count>12</count>
        <status>
            <stockNo>1000</stockNo>
            <itemNo>500</itemNo>
            <name>frock</name>
        </status>
<status>
                <stockNo>1000</stockNo>
                <itemNo>500</itemNo>
                <name>bag</name>
            </status>
<gage>3</gage>
</statuses> filtering is not happening

Comment: Maybe the parameter is passed ok, but it's the condition that's wrong? You're comparing an element with a string. Maybe text(name) = '$rendered_id'? Does it work if you hardcode a value instead of your parameter?

Comment: yes. It is working fine when I hard cord it.

Comment: i found the problem. It should be <xsl:if test="name = $rendered_id"/> that is without single quotes for the parameter